# Google cloud cors multiple accounts?

Tags: cors, google-cloud-platform, gsutil

I am wondering how do I setup multiple Google accounts using cors. From below image(reference(2) url), it's clear stated that we can do multiple accounts setup on cors.

[image]

Can someone assist me? FYI, I followed this approach https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cors

Ref:
1. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin

2. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/put-bucket-cors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're confusing some things here. [Google accounts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Account) have nothing to with CORS.

As for allowing multiple origins for a bucket, using the gsutil example [you provided](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cors) as a base, the JSON used contains an origin key/value pair. The value is an array and can contain multiple comma-separated values:

```
[
    {
        "origin": [
            "http://origin1.appspot.com",
            "http://origin2.appspot.com"
        ],
        "responseHeader": [
            "Content-Type"
        ],
        "method": [
            "GET"
        ],
        "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
    }
]
```

Another option is to supply multiple objects, if you for example want to use GET methods for one origin and GET & DELETE for another origin:

```
[
    {
        "origin": [
            "http://origin1.appspot.com"
        ],
        "responseHeader": [
            "Content-Type"
        ],
        "method": [
            "GET"
        ],
        "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
    },
    {
        "origin": [
            "http://origin2.appspot.com"
        ],
        "responseHeader": [
            "Content-Type"
        ],
        "method": [
            "GET",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
    }
]
```